# onSnapshot permission error when matching custom claim to Firestore wildcard

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Im trying to allow the document reading for only users who have in their custom claim the "houseId" that is identical to the document id.

This is the Firestore rule that is not working:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /houses/{houseId} { 
      allow read: if request.auth.token.houseId == houseId;
    }
  }
}
```

I also try the following code, but it didn't work either:

```
match /houses/{houseId} { 
  allow read: if request.auth.token.houseId == resource.data.houseId;
}
```

Instead, if I use the "string" version of the houseId it works.

```
match /houses/{houseId} { 
  allow read: if request.auth.token.houseId == 'T45bpx2wzskdtxoowfIw';
}
```

My client side code for fetching the data is (the inCharge field of the house document is just for querying the specific document where the user has been added):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscriber = db.collection('houses')
    .where('inCharge.inChargeId', '==', user.userId)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const houses = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        houses.push({
          ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          houseId: documentSnapshot.id
        });
      });
      dispatch(housesActions.setHouses(houses));
      setIsLoading(false);
    });

  return () => subscriber();

}, [])
```

My user claims are for example like this:

```
User1: {role: 'inCharge', houseId: T45bpx2wzskdtxoowfIw}
user2: {role: 'viewer', houseId: T45bpx2wzskdtxoowfIw}
...
```

The documents are like this:

```
houseId:
  name: 'Name of the house'
  createdAt: timestamp of creation
  inCharge: {
    name: 'name of the inCharge person'
    inChargeId: 'id of the inCharge person'
  }
  otherFIelds:
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not work because [Firestore security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Be sure to read that documentation, and [this blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).

It seems that you're depending on the rules to filter out documents that match the user's custom claims.  This isn't going to work.  Your query needs to apply the filter, and the rules can just check to make sure that the filter is correct.

In your specific case, it looks like each user can access no more than exactly one document in the houses collection, identified by the houseId in their custom claims.  Since that's the case, the best thing you can do here is simply `get()`  that document by its ID instead of querying using the other filter that you have now.  You can then check that document to see if it contains the values you expect.

You can also try to use the same query you have now, but filter the documentId for the one you provide, which must match the one in custom claims:

```
.where(firebase.FieldValue.documentId(), '==', houseId)
```

But this seems more complicated to me since your rules require that each user can only read their one document.

Comment: Thanks @Doug for your orientation, you're right! I think that security rules only evaluate the actual properties of the document in the database, but no, it take in consideration all possible cases. The link you post describe my error "Firestore security rules are not filters": "The reason for this behavior is that when Cloud Firestore applies your security rules, it evaluates the query against its potential result set, not against the actual properties of documents in your database. If a query could potentially include documents that violate your security rules, the query will fail.". Thanks!